# Dynamic AddDbContext and async service

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

My Net 7 API application is multitenant.

I manage the change of the connection string in Program.cs with this code:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DbContext>((services, options) =>
    {
        var tenantService = services.GetRequiredService<ITenantService>();
        var tenantConnectionString = tenantService.GetConnectionString();
        options.UseSqlServer(tenantConnectionString, x => x.UseHierarchyId().UseNetTopologySuite())
        .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(CoreEventId.PossibleIncorrectRequiredNavigationWithQueryFilterInteractionWarning));
    });
```

I have a TenantService which returns the database connection string for the tenant by examining a claim present in the token. Everything is working correctly.

Now, I have started a new project where the retrieval of the ConnectionString is slightly different because it needs to be read from an external API that I invoke using

```
await httpClient.GetAsync(url)
```

This call makes the entire scenario asynchronous, so I have some issues with the previous configuration.

In this case, I should retrieve the tenantService asynchronously. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the url is retrieved once during startup, then you can do it synchronously, and keep the rest of the code the same.

If the url is fully dynamic and you'll have multiple values at runtime, then the standard practice is to introduce a *factory* type and use that instead of injecting a db context directly.